# Multiple instance jquery function with bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, bootstrap-4

I am trying to run jquery function once modal is shown, but I close modal by clicking on the side or one close button and then open I find multiple instances of the inner function running.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $(".test").click(function () {
                    var cid = $(this).attr('cid');
                    $("#post-form").one('submit',function (event){
                        event.preventDefault();
                        $.ajax({
                        url: '{% url 'create_request' %}',
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: {
                            'cid': cid,
                            'req_num' : $('#request_number').val(),
                        },
                        success: function (data) {

                            console.log("success")
                            if (data['request']=='0')
                            {
                                alert("Request is already there");
                            }
                            else if(data['request']=='1')
                            {
                                alert("Not enough components:(");
                            }
                            $("#exampleModal").modal('hide');
                        }
                    })
                    })

                })
            })
        </script>
```

test is the class given to button which opens bootstrap modal
post-form is the id given to my form

Answer (score 0):

Attach the submit event listener outside the click function, otherwise you will create one listener per click.

```js
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#post-form").one('submit',function (event){
            event.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: '{% url 'create_request' %}',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    'cid': cid,
                    'req_num' : $('#request_number').val(),
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data['request']=='0')
                    {
                        alert("Request is already there");
                    }
                    else if(data['request']=='1')
                    {
                        alert("Not enough components:(");
                    }
                    $("#exampleModal").modal('hide');
                }
            })
        })
    })
```

This will of course break the context for `this` in `$(this).attr('cid');`, so you will have to update that to reflect the changes. I'd suggest placing it inside a hidden field in your form, or as an attribute to your modal, whatever is more convenient.

Comment: I need to run ajax only once the post is submitted

Comment: Apologies, I misunderstood your question. I have updated my answer

Comment: thank you for the suggestion that won't probably help, is there to track closing of modal so probably I can detect if modal has been closed so I can end the outer function right there